# "Sets" of a particular enum type but with generics

Tags: java, generics, enums

Let's say I have an abstract class

```
public abstract class Trainer<T extends Animal>{}
```

I have specific trainers like :

```
public DogTrainer extends Trainer<Dog>{}
public HorseTrainer extends Trainer<Horse>{}
```

Each of these 'trainers' has a set of fixed tricks they can train the animal to do, which I'd like to use Enums for. So I have an interface:

```
public interface TrainingActions<T extends Animal>{}
```

and in each of the trainers, I have an Enum that implements this interface. So:

```
public DogTrainer extends Trainer<Dog>{
  public enum Trainables implements TrainingActions<Dog>{
    BARK, BITE, ROLLOVER, FETCH;
  }
}

public HorseTrainer extends Trainer<Horse>{
  public enum Trainables implements TrainingActions<Horse>{
    JUMP, TROT, REARUP;
  }
}
```

Now in the each of the Trainer classes, I'd like a method say 'trainingComplete' that takes one of the Enums as an input and saves it to a set. So

```
public DogTrainer extends Trainer<Dog>{
  public enum Trainables implements TrainingActions<Dog>{
    BARK, BITE, ROLLOVER, FETCH;
  }
  public Set<Trainables> completed = new HashSet<Trainables>();
  public void trainingComplete(Trainables t){completed.add(t);}
}
```

However, instead of defining the 'completed' set in each of the specific Trainers and the 'trainingComplete' method in each of the trainers, I'd like something in the parent 'Trainers' class that can be Enum-type enforced... So it's a weird combination of Enums and generics.

Is this possible?

Comment: In each declaration, `Enum` should be `enum`.

Comment: Show the definition of Animal

Comment: @Bohemian, could you tell what you needed to see with the def. of Animal? I guess for this analogy, it would just be a few common animal properties (average weight, genus, species) and maybe a few common methods... where were you going with the Animal definition..?

Comment: For `I'd like something in the parent 'Animal' class that can be Enum-type enforced` I think you mean `I'd like something in the parent ***'Trainer'*** class that can be Enum-type enforced`, right?

Comment: Your data model is complex.  This is probably a red flag that your solution is possibly fragile or may be difficult to maintain (or work with).  You have your `enum` classes implement an interface, but you've defined no constant-specific methods and there are no class methods in your enums; it seems to me that this renders the interface pointless?  Is the interface just a marker interface? What is the interface definition?

Comment: I'm wondering if your expectation is that you'll be able to supply a different interface declaration for every concrete generic parameter type (eg. a different interface for TrainingActions<Dog> and TrainingActions<Horse>).  If so, this is not how generic type parameters work with interface declarations.  All implementers of TrainingActions<T> will need to implement the same set of methods.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To specify a bound to an interface and that it be an enum, you need a generic *intersection*, which looks like:

```
class MyClass<T extends Enum<T> & SomeInterface> {}
```

Note that when intersecting a class and an interface(s), the class must appear before the interface(s).

In this case, the generics Kung Fu you want is one level more complicated, because the interface of the TrainingActions enum must itself refer back to the animal type.

```
class Trainer<A extends Animal, T extends Enum<T> & TrainingActions<A>> {}
```

A complete working example, based on your posted code, that compiles is:

```
public class Animal {}

public interface TrainingActions<T extends Animal> {}

/**
 * A trainer that can teach an animal a suitable set of tricks
 * @param <A> The type of Animal
 * @param <T> The enum of TrainingActions that can be taught to the specified Animal
 */
public abstract class Trainer<A extends Animal, T extends Enum<T> & TrainingActions<A>> {
    private Set<T> completed = new HashSet<T>();
    public void trainingComplete(T t) {
        completed.add(t);
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {};

public class DogTrainer extends Trainer<Dog, DogTrainer.Trainables> {
    public enum Trainables implements TrainingActions<Dog> {
        BARK, BITE, ROLLOVER, FETCH;
    }
}
```

But I would go one step further and define several `TrainingActions` enums in the class of the particular `Animal` to which they apply:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    public enum BasicTrainables implements TrainingActions<Dog> {
        SIT, COME, STAY, HEEL;
    }
    public enum IntermediateTrainables implements TrainingActions<Dog> {
        BARK, BITE, ROLLOVER, FETCH;
    }
    public enum AdvacedTrainables implements TrainingActions<Dog> {
        SNIFF_DRUGS, FIND_PERSON, ATTACK, GUARD;
    }
};

public class PuppyTrainer extends Trainer<Dog, Dog.BasicTrainables> {}

public class ObedienceTrainer extends Trainer<Dog, Dog.IntermediateTrainables> {}

public class PoliceTrainer extends Trainer<Dog, Dog.AdvacedTrainables> {}
```

Comment: +1 Had a complicated answer in mind, but this is just awesome!

Comment: The main point here is the way you bound a generic parameter to be two types. You can apply this technique wherever you have control to do so.

Comment: OK see edited answer for solution not requiring change to Animal, but to Trainer

Comment: In that veing, I tried adding a 'Set' type variable to the parent Trainer classes that would only accept Enum values of a particular training action. So I was trying to do something like

`public Set<? extends Enum<?> & TrainingActions<T extends Animal>> completedActions`

but that doesn't quite work...

Comment: @Bohemian I was trying your last suggestion, but couldn't get it to work. I'm getting an error with trying to do `& Enum<T>`. Also, I need `T` to extends `Animal` because I have other methods in `Trainer` that work directly on the animal `T`...

Comment: The design seems a bit messy. You can add `& Animal` to the bound, but I think you need to rethink your classes and their responsibilities

Comment: sorry... still having trouble following this... adding `& Animal` to the bound...?

Comment: @anishthecoder I was think that, but now I'm not so sure it's what you want. Before I guess again, is it that you want a Trainer to train a particular Animal and the Animal is to be defined as being able to do an enum of particular tricks? And you can't modify Animal?

Comment: @Bohemian More like I want the Trainer for a particular animal to be able to do an enum of particular tricks. So while `DogTrainer` might have an enum of tricks as above `ModernDogTrainer` might have a different set of tricks but because both extend `Trainer<Dog>`, their tricks would apply only to Dogs. So I don't want `ModernDogTrainer`s tricks to be available to `DogTrainer`

Comment: I kind of feel that there is a type parameter of Animal missing in Trainer. In OP's original question, Trainer<A> can refer to the type of animal, but in your suggested approach, we can't (Though in the example code of OP, it is not showing the usage...)

Comment: so I think it may look something like `Trainer<A, T extends TrainingAction<A> & Enum<T> >`

Comment: @AdrianShum You were (almost) right - with intersections that are a mix of classes and interfaces, the class must come first. See edited (rewritten) answer with working examples

Comment: @anishthecoder OK I have basically rewritten the answer. I think it is now what you want and can use.

Comment: @RohitJain Thanks :). I've added some more generics Kung Fu if you're intesested

Comment: Loved the last approach with different enums. Nice decryption of the problem BTW. :)

Comment: I know that this is Java, and we love enterprise, and advanced generics impress beginners, but in this case my vote is: **overengineered**

Comment: Also I would use wildcard `?` instead of `A` if you don't use `A` type explicity.

Comment: @killer_PL I'm sure `A` is used in `Trainer` - we just weren't shown any code. Over-engineered? I dunno - I kinda like it. It expresses the relationships correctly. What's the alternative then? Without this kind of generics you could define a class that teaches horse tricks to a dog.

Comment: I'm just wondering why to create interface, only to enforce enum after a while. I think that just question provided design is already not quite good. Going this way will always cause limitations or code overhead. Propably better will be more collections, agregations etc. to ensure type safety and elasticyty together (different trainers with different abilities to different animals in any combinations, including mixing, **not locking a person to be a super-specific training master for some super specific abilities of specific animal and nothing more**).

Comment: Of course I mean a `"John than can teach horse to trot and a dog to bark"`, not `"John that can teach horse or dog to trot or bark"`. So i would go to some training abilities for specific animals that can be added to teachers independly, or even a group of abilities that are more general (almost every animal we can teach to run). But of course this is not design question.

Comment: @Bohemian Thank you! that second bound on the `Animal` class worked like a charm!

Comment: I can see how `HEEL` might be a basic trainable, but `HEAL` definitely seems more like an advanced trainable to me, perhaps one specific to a `ClericTrainer`. :)

Comment: @Tom Ya got me there! Lol

Answer (score 1):

Despite design analysis, I think the most your-situation (closest to your already created design) answer is:

- your `DogTrainer.Trainables` is `TrainingActions<Dog>`
- your `HorseTrainer.Trainables` is `TrainingActions<Horse>`

**Generally, your `Trainables` is already a `TrainingActions<T extends Animal>`**

so you can just provide `Set<TrainingActions<T>> completed`, because **you already have your animal information in `T`**:

```
abstract class Trainer<T extends Animal> {
    Set<TrainingActions<T>> completed = new HashSet<TrainingActions<T>>();

    public void add(TrainingActions<T> t ) {
        completed.add( t );
    }
}
```

And you have exactly what you want.

Usage:

```
DogTrainer tr = new DogTrainer();
tr.add( DogTrainer.Trainables.BITE );
```

If you are sure you want to enforce an Enum for your interface:

```
public <E extends Enum<?> & TrainingActions<T>> void add( E t ) {
   completed.add( t );
}
```

Comment: I was using precisely this strategy in the interim =) But it unfortunately doesn't prevent someone from adding a PoliceDogTrainer's Trainable to a PuppyTrainer..

Comment: @anishthecoder like I mentioned in comments in accepted answer - I think that problems don't lie in what you say, but overall not best design - specifing `PoliceDogTrainer` etc. is like going into maximum inheritance usage in OOP - you lost with too resticted types. I think that there shoulb be more plain aggregation etc. instead of complicated type hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

**I will post that for further consideration, even there is already accepted answer**

If you read this question, consider using more loose coupled elements, with aggregation etc. instead of highly specific and complicated type hierarchy and generics.

With just plain aggregation you can achieve at least the same type & logical safety, but loose coupled design. Like I mentioned in comments:

> Propably better will be more collections, agregations etc. to ensure
>   type safety and elasticyty together (different trainers with different
>   abilities to different animals in any combinations, including mixing,
>   not locking a person to be a super-specific training master for some
>   super specific abilities of specific animal **and nothing more**).
>
> Of course I mean a "John than can teach horse to trot and a dog to
>   bark", not "John that can teach horse or dog to trot or bark"

Comment: Could you give a working example? I'm interested to compare your solution with the accepted answer

Comment: See my other response. I don't have exact or similar implementation. I;m just generally promoting "composition over inheritance". Because whu `DogTrainer` can't be ALSO a `HorseTrainer`? So, for example, you could have a `Trainer` or `Person` with `List<TrainingSkill>` nad if that person is able to train some entity then **it has a skill** in skill collection. Then, logic from `DogTrainer` class can moved to `DogTrainingSkill`

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can move your `Trainables` , `Set<Trainables> completed` and `trainingComplete(Trainables t)` to the class Trainer.

This way you no need to write these code each DogTrainer, HorseTrainer .. and so on...

```
 abstract class Trainer<T extends Animal>{
     public enum Trainables implements TrainingActions<Animal>{
            BARK, BITE, ROLLOVER, FETCH;
     }
      public Set<Trainables> completed = new HashSet<Trainables>();
      public void trainingComplete(Trainables t){completed.add(t);}
}
```

Otherwise make trainingComplete(Trainables t) abstract and you need to implement in each Trainer implementaion clasees.

```
abstract class Trainer<T extends Animal>{
     public enum Trainables implements TrainingActions<Animal>{
            BARK, BITE, ROLLOVER, FETCH;
     }
      public Set<Trainables> completed = new HashSet<Trainables>();
      abstract public void trainingComplete(Trainables t);
}
```

Now your DogTrainer and HorseTrainer are implementing `trainingComplete(Trainables t)`

```
 public class DogTrainer extends Trainer<Dog>{      
     public void trainingComplete(Trainables t){
          completed.add(t);
     }
 }

 public class HorseTrainer extends Trainer<Horse>{     
     public void trainingComplete(Trainables t){
           completed.add(t);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Be patient. A horse trainer doesn't usually teach a horse to bark... they might be able to, but that be one odd horse. By the question the  trainables need to be separate. Therefore this is not a solution.